# Cannot control geometry settings to give different margins for front cover and inside a book

Tags: formatting, geometry, layout

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass[a4,english,11pt]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=170mm,lmargin=0mm,rmargin=0mm,
bindingoffset=0mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %

\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{layout} %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\frontmatter

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\parindent=0pt

\mainmatter

\Large{I want the left and right margins set to zero so that the 240mm x 170mm image A \\[6pt] (my front cover) aligns with the crop marks - i.e. occupies the full page.}

\begin{titlepage}

\includegraphics[width=170mm,height=240mm]{example-image-A}%

\end{titlepage}

\Large{Then the margins and binding-offset change to align the contents inside the book.}

\newgeometry{paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=25mm,
tmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm} %

    \begin{center}

        \vspace*{18mm}
        \Huge\textbf{Text inside the book} \\[6pt]
                \huge{crop marks have moved}
            
        \vspace{24mm}
                \Large
        Text entry:\\[6pt]
                width=132mm \\[6pt] left margin=25mm, right margin=13.5mm \\[6pt]
                bindingoffset=12.5mm \\[6pt]
                topmargin=25mm, bottommargin=18mm
                
                \vspace{48mm}
                \Large
                2022-11-03
                
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cover is an image, you can simply use `\includepdf` of package `pdfpages`. A somehow reduced example would be:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=25mm,tmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %

\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\includepdf[noautoscale=true,width=170mm,height=240mm]{example-image-a}%

\mainmatter

\begin{center}

  \vspace*{18mm}
  \Huge\textbf{Text inside the book} \\[6pt]
  \huge crop marks have moved
  
  \vspace{24mm}
  \Large
  Text entry:\\[6pt]
  width=132mm \\[6pt] left margin=25mm, right margin=13.5mm \\[6pt]
  bindingoffset=12.5mm \\[6pt]
  topmargin=25mm, bottommargin=18mm
  
  \vspace{48mm}
  \Large
  2022-11-03
  
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So you do not need to change the margins for the cover page.

BTW: Commands like `\huge` do not have an argument. They are switches.

If you absolutely need to use dvi mode, you can adapt a similar functionality to `\includepdf` using package `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=25mm,tmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %

\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=170mm,height=240mm]{example-image-a}}
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\mainmatter

\begin{center}

  \vspace*{18mm}
  \Huge\textbf{Text inside the book} \\[6pt]
  \huge crop marks have moved
  
  \vspace{24mm}
  \Large
  Text entry:\\[6pt]
  width=132mm \\[6pt] left margin=25mm, right margin=13.5mm \\[6pt]
  bindingoffset=12.5mm \\[6pt]
  topmargin=25mm, bottommargin=18mm
  
  \vspace{48mm}
  \Large
  2022-11-03
  
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your answer (twice) but got no image showing; no errors either.

Comment: @keith77777 I've added an image of the three pages produced by my example (using either `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`). If an *unchanged* copy of my code does not produce this result, please check your log file for *strange messages* or show it. If you've changed my code, please check your changes.

Comment: Yes, the log file suggests running in pdf mode - where it works perfectly.

Comment: However, I am editing a long maths book and I'm used to dvi mode.  I could leave this feature out until the very last moment, but I do wonder if it would be possible to reach a solution based on the geometry package?

Comment: @keith77777 There was no information in your question that you do use dvi mode and that you cannot use pdf mode. Because using `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex` in pdf mode is usually the default, my answer is about this. BTW: You cannot change paper size options within `\newgeometry`.

Comment: @keith77777 But meanwhile I've also added a dvi mode suggestion.

Comment: That works perfectly - many thanks.